# AngularJS - Select dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my first AngularJS project and am having an issue with my selects. The options are populated and if I focus the select I can use the keyboard to arrow up/down to change which option is selected. However, the dropdown itself never shows up and I can't figure out why. I am using Bootstrap as well if that makes any difference.

JS Code:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/Mortality/GetMortalityReasonsList',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function (success) {
  $scope.reasons = success.data;
}, function (error) {
  debugger;
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="reason">Reason</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="reason" ng-model="log.reason" ng-options="reason as reason.Name for reason in reasons track by reason.Id"></select>
</div>
```

Response:

```
[
   {
      "Id": 638,
      "Name": "Adjusted Deaths",
      "Code": "11",
      "CultureCode": "en-US"
   },
   ...
]
```

EDIT: The field itself is being populated properly. I just don't have the dropdown menu. I'm guessing it is a CSS issue of some kind but am not sure why it won't work. The issue occurs even if I populate the list with a hardcoded list rather than making a network call.
[image: Reasons are populated]

Comment: post your json response

Comment: Does calling apply make a difference? `$scope.reasons = success.data; $scope.$apply();`

Comment: Added response. When I add $scope.$apply() it says $digest already in progress.

Comment: unless you have some type of error, this is not possible.  I created a [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lIBB2ngbiUN8HDm6EUg7?p=preview), which seems to be working fine.  I included bootstrap and included jquery ahead of Angular.  But doesn't matter, it always shows the dropdown.  Are you sure, your console is devoid of any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select class="form-control" id="reason" ng-model="reason" ng-options="reason as reason.Name for reason in optionsdownload"></select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3tZrnr4EnPQWePDi7kf3?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Angular's material design library and Bootstrap don't play nicely together. Removed the MD library and it started working fine again.